# nested struct in C

Tags: c, nested, structure

```
struct s{ 
int a; 
struct s b;
};
```

The above code segment throws the error  `error: field 'b' has incomplete type` while

```
struct s{ 
int a; 
struct s *b;
};
```

doesn't give any error. I don't understand why this is allowed for pointers but not for the non-pointer variable !!

Comment: because compiler has to know struct size

Comment: How could a structure contain something the same size as itself?

Comment: Because in the second case you hold a pointer, the size of which the compiler can know even before it has seen the entire struct definition.

Comment: @Unni: What do you mean "why"? How do you imagine yourself a struct type that directly contains itself as a member? That would constitute a type that is infinitely nested into itself. It would produce a type of infinite size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q:  What are incomplete types?

A:  An incomplete type is a type which has the identifier but lacks information needed to determine the size of the identifier.

- The ‘void’ type is an incomplete type.
- A union/structure type whose members which are not yet specified.
- ‘void’ type cannot be completed.

To complete an incomplete type, we need to specify the missing
   information.

Example:

```
struct Employee *ptr;   // Here 'Employee' is incomplete
```

- C/C++ allows pointers to incomplete types.

To make 'Employee' complete, we need to specify missing information like shown below

```
typedef struct Employee
{
    char name[25];
    int age;
    int employeeID;
    char department[25];
}EMP;
```

In your case,

```
struct s
{ 
    int a; 
    struct s b; // Structure is incomplete.
}// Till this point the structure is incomplete.
```

The `struct s b;` the `structure s` is incomplete. We can declare a pointer to incomplete type not a variable.

Answer (score 5):

Class members must have a complete type when they are declared, so that their size can be used to determine the class layout.

Within the class definition, the class itself is incomplete, so you can't declare a member of the same type. That would be impossible anyway (at least if there are any other members), since the class would have to be larger than itself.

A pointer is a complete type, even if the type it points to isn't, so you can declare a class member to be a pointer to the class type.

<sub>(Note: I use the word "class" since I'm a C++ programmer. I just noticed that the question is also tagged C, and C++ has since been removed. I believe the answer is still correct in that language, if you replace "class" with "structure", but I'm not completely sure since they are different languages. It would be better if you only asked about one language, since there are differences (sometimes major, sometimes subtle) between languages.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

To adequately define s, the compiler needs to know the size of s.  In the first example, the size of s depends on the size of s, but not in the second.

In the first example, by defintion, `sizeof(s) = sizeof(int) + sizeof(s) + padding`.  If we try to solve this equation for `sizeof(s)`, we get `0 = sizeof(int) + padding`, which clearly is impossible.

In the second, `sizeof(s) = sizeof(int) + sizeof(s*) + padding`.  If we assume that `sizeof(s*) ~= sizeof(int)`, then `sizeof(s) = 2*sizeof(int) + padding`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the extra asterisks in `struct s **b**` are given for emphasis and not as some kind of demented pointer declaration. (Please don't do that! It's much easier to analyze someone's code if it's presented exactly as it runs.)

When you do this without declaring `b` as a pointer:

```
struct s{ 
  int a; 
  struct s b;
};
```

the compiler doesn't know how much space it needs to allocate for the `b` field, since at that point you haven't finished defining `struct s`. In fact, it would be impossible for the compiler to define this particular structure: no matter how many bytes it allocated for `struct s`, it would have to add 4 more to make room for the `int a` field.

Declaring `b` to be a pointer to `struct s` makes things easier:

```
struct s{ 
  int a; 
  struct s *b;
};
```

No matter how many fields you add to `struct s`, the compiler knows that the `b` field only needs to contain the address of the struct, and that doesn't change based on how large the struct itself it.

Comment: Sorry about the extra asterisk symbol. I put it there to bold the variable b. But that didn't get properly formatted.